# Python quality inspection with opencv (ssim)

Tags: python, opencv, ssim

I'm currently an intern at a quality inspector company. My job is to write a program that can detect faulty products (for example, missing screw). They take a picture of every single product. My idea is that I choose an image which could serve as a benchmark and I would compare the other images to that, with the SSIM score, and maybe display the faulty part with a rectangle. Is this a viable idea? (Its a strange internship, because it seems like I'm the only one who can code there...) that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: SSIM is entirely unsuitable here. further, just taking snapshots from any which way is not proper optical inspection. **lighting** and object-camera pose need to be tightly controlled, unless you want to make your life needlessly hard. since this is more of a discussion and less of a one-question-one-answer situation, I'd recommend other venues to learn about OpenCV, computer vision, machine vision, optical inspection, ...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds good idea if your goal is to classify different objects within images comparing benchmark image.
But in my experience, SSIM score was sensitive to angle, light or environment.

So in conclusion, if your goal is to classify different objects in images, your idea would work. But if your goal is to classify exactly same objects, it might not be able to classify.

Comment: Yeah this is my concern aswell